# Big pictures to appendix

Tags: graphics

Is there a possibility to define figures in the sections and then use a parameter/label to tell TeX, that this picture shall printed in an extra Appendix.
I would like to use this way for big pictures, par example for screenshots; because it is not really nice to have this big pictures in the sections.

Comment: Should the figure be printed in the section (smaller) and in the appendix, or only in the appendix?

Comment: That would be very good, if I could also define the scaling and a rotation of 90 degree (In Appendix on picture at one side, turned and maximal size) . But I am also happy without that.

Comment: @user146304: could you please rephrase your question. I don't really understand what you are after, there are some typos

Comment: @user146304 Well, I'm not aware of any package giving this sort of options, so it seems that you'll have to write your own macro for this. I'll see, if I find the time later this day, I'll try it...

Comment: I thought a bit about this and I don't have a simple solution. I'll post my ideas and the problems I see, maybe one of the more experienced users (like @ChristianHupfer) can help.

Answer (score 2):

## *NOT a working solution, only some ideas that could help solving this*

---

Firstly I'm not a big fan of redefining the LaTeX environments, so I think we'll have to define a new environment which I now called `appendixfig`. Currently, I also ignored the option to define whether the image should or shouldn't be printed at the place of its definition.

Printing data in two different places reminds me on the `collect` package which allows you to collect data in an "array". Later on, you can then print this array. That's almost what we need.

Here is an MWE of that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{lscape}

\definecollection{appendixfig}

\newenvironment{appendixfig}{}{}

\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{appendixfig}[1]{%
            \appendixfig
            \@nameuse{collect*}{appendixfig}{\begin{figure}[#1]}{\end{figure}}{\begin{landscape}}{\end{landscape}}%
        }{%
            \@nameuse{endcollect*} %
            \endappendixfig
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{appendixfig}{!htb}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/02-merge-image}
        \caption{The picture}
    \end{appendixfig}
    
    \newpage
    \appendix
    \section{Figures}
    \includecollection{appendixfig}
\end{document}
```

Pretty straightforward I would say. The problem is, that you will write everything inside the new environment, what you would write in the default figure environment. Well, in fact, that's not really a problem, the problem with that is, that the output in the appendix will be *exaclty* the same as the one inside the document... I didn't find a nice solution to pass the orientation of `angle=90, origin=c` or the `height=0.9\textheight` or whatever.

A partly solution could be the use of the `lscape` package. This lets you wrap some code around a `landscape` environment, so at least the appendix images would appear in landscape, but still be the same height/width of the original image.

A second problem I see is the caption. It would be great to have the same numbering in the appendix-figure-caption as you have on the original figure. Maybe you could even let LaTeX automatically print add a sting behind the caption text referring to the page the original image is located at.

All these problems normally are no big deal, but inside the `collect` environment, I can't figure out how to do this.

---

As said, take this answer as a starting point. With a bit of luck, a more experienced LaTeX developer or hacker comes along and provides a working solution.